# Insert a div after every four items pulled from a database

Tags: php, sql

Right now, I'm using SQL/PHP and a while loop to pull items from a database. It works fine but I need to insert a div after every four items pulled. I have no idea how I would approach this, I have tried messing with the loops but can't seems to get it to work. How would I accomplish something like this?

It works now:

```
<?php 
    $i = 3;
    $ii = 4;
    while($usersrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($users)) {
        $i++;
        $ii++;
            if (($i % 4) == 0) {
                echo "
                    <div class='item'>
                    <div class='row'>
                    ";
                    }

                echo "
                    <div class='col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3'>
                        <a class='thumbnail'>
                            <img src='images/$usersrow[picture]' alt='$usersrow[name]'>
                            <div class='caption'>
                                $usersrow[name]<blockquote>$usersrow[quote]</blockquote>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    ";

                if (($ii % 4) == 0) {
                    echo "
                        </div><!--/.row-->
                        </div><!--/.item-->
                        ";
                        }

                } 
                echo "</div><!--/.row--> </div><!--/.item-->";
                ?>
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: @John Conde: There's a reason why that off-topic close option was removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a counter in your while loop and then check if the counter is divisible by 4 to output the div. For example:

```
$i = 0;
while () {
     $i++;

     // Output normal items
     if (($i % 4) == 0) {
          // If the counter $i is divisible by 4 output a div
          echo '<div></div>';
     }
}
```

Comment: How would I wrap the divs around every four items? I edited the question to show my code.

Comment: You're code is right, except the counter ($i++) is only being incremented every 4th time (which is never at this point). You need to move that $i++ to the first line under the while statement.